# Magen Avraham - Practically no Plag HaMinḥah or just no Plag HaMinḥah in winter?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, posek-psak-decisor-ruling, astronomy, mathematics

Calling all science and math-oriented Judaism.SE-ers!
According to the website MyZmanim.com, today's [Halachic times](http://www.zmanimclock.com/shaot) where I work are as follows (only a handful of times are shown because the question would be tedious to edit otherwise):

> **Dawn        עלות השחר**
>   90 minutes as degrees, bef. sunrise **5:34:28** 90 דקות במעלות, קודם הנץ
>
> Fixed 72 minutes before sunrise **6:07:32**    72 דקות שוות קודם הנץ
>
> 72 minutes as 16.1 degrees  **5:53:58** 72 דקות לפי 16.1 מעלות
>
> **Earliest Talis & Tefillin     זמן ציצית ותפילין**
>   Sun is 11.5 degrees below horizon   **6:18:58** 11.5 מעלות תחת האופק
>
> Sun is 11 degrees below horizon **6:21:43** 11 מעלות תחת האופק
>
> Sun is 10.2 degrees below horizon   **6:26:08** 10.2 מעלות תחת האופק
>
> **Sunrise       הנץ החמה**
>   In a level region   **7:19:32** במישור
>
> **Latest Shema Magen Avraham        סוף זמן קריאת שמע
>   מגן אברהם**
>   Using "90 minutes..." as dawn and nightfall **8:48:59** לפי 90 דקות במעלות
>   Using "Fixed 72 minutes..." **9:05:31** לפי 72 דקות שוות
>   Using "72 minutes as 16.1 degrees"  **8:58:44** לפי 72 דקות במעלות
>
> Midday & Midnight       **12:03:30**    חצות
>
> **Earliest Mincha       מנחה גדולה**
>
> 30 fixed minutes after midday   **12:33:30**    30 דקות שוות אחר חצות
>   Gra & Baal Tanya    **12:27:10**    גר"א ובעל התניא
>   LeChumra    **12:33:30**    לחומרא
>   **Magen Avraham**
>   Using "Fixed 72 minutes..." **12:33:10**    מגן אברהם
>   לפי 72 דקות שוות
>
> **Mincha Ketana     מנחה קטנה**
>   Gra & Baal Tanya    **2:49:09** גר"א ובעל התניא
>   **Magen Avraham מגן אברהם**
>   Using "Fixed 72 minutes..." **3:31:09** 
>   לפי 72 דקות שוות
>
> **Plag HaMincha         פלג המנחה**
>   Gra & Baal Tanya    **3:48:19** גר"א ובעל התניא
>   **Magen Avraham מגן אברהם**
>   Using "Fixed 72 minutes..." **4:45:19** 
>   לפי 72 דקות שוות
>
> **Sunset        שקיעת החמה**
>   In a level region   **4:47:29** במישור

Does this mean that the Magen Avraham holds of only a very minuscule Plag HaMinḥah? Or is there something going on mathematically that just makes it nearly impossible to have a Plag in the winter? Is there something in this Shittah that could explain why many synagogues Daven Minḥah on Friday evenings in the summer well after Plag HaMinḥah as usually published in most calendars? Is M"A's Shittah just that much later?

Comment: Where do you work? First of all, I want to compare the times with other sites in order to be sure that MyZmanim is at least correct.

Comment: A nitpick: _P'lag_ is a time of the day, not a span of time. Everyone holds of a minuscule _p'lag_: it's an instant.

Comment: If you [look here](http://bit.ly/T8JX0X) you will find a "halachic time app" which tells you how many minutes are in a halachic hour on the day you view the app. During this time of the year, you will notice that a halachic hour is short (only 50 minutes) During the summer, the halachic hour tends to be longer (close to 70 minutes) This would make different key times during the day closer or further apart from eachother. Also during the winter, "Sunset" takes much quicker (sometimes only 10 minutes) while in the summer it can take much longer (close to 20 minutes).

Comment: @msh210, thank you. I am referring to the span of time between Plag and Sheki'ah.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/50716

Comment: @msh210 I don't think that's true. The Gemara asks if it's talking about פלג קמא or פלג אחרונה

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The MA holds that we split up the 12 hours of a day from Alot HaShachar (the beginning of day) to Tzeit HaKochavim (the end of the day). The Gra holds that the 12 hours are split from sunrise to sunset independent of what is considered day or night.

All agree that noon must be when the sun is highest in the sky. (This can be proven from the gemara that says they waited for mincha until 6.5 hours because they wanted to make sure by seeing the shadows grow.)

All agree also that Alot HaShachar is at observed dawn (when you can see light in the eastern sky) which is usually 60-90 minutes before sunrise (at normal latitudes).

(Note: from here on I will be using minutes based on Israel's latitude on an equinox. For other locations everything scales accordingly. Additionally, I assume the length of a 'mil' to be 18 minutes (the most conventional opinion). For other opinions just scale accordingly.)

There are two opinions regarding when sunset and tzeit is. To (greatly) summarize, Rabbeinu Tam holds that day ends 58.5 min after sunset, followed by 13.5 minutes of doubt, and then nightfall 72 minutes after sunset. The Gra holds that sunset is the beginning of the doubt period and nightfall is 13.5 minutes later.

So, for the Magen Avraham, to ensure that noon stays in the middle of the day, he *must* hold of RT's version of nightfall (and that Alot is by definition the equivalent amount of time before sunrise). As such, his plag, which is 90 minutes (1.25 of his 'hours') before nightfall, ends up about 18 minutes before the Gra's sunset. But since he is holding of RT, day for him ends 76.5 minutes later! (By the solstices, MA plag can be between approx 6-30 minutes before Gra's sunset for Jerusalem latitude.)

Since the majority of the world follows Gra times (lechumra and lekula) the website likely didn't even bother to give you the end of RT's day. But it exists!

This explains your issue with the times.

Comment: Double AA - Good answer. BTW, where do you get that the time between Alos and sunrise is "by definition" equivalent to the time between sunset and tzais?

Comment: @Dave For the MA, the time between Alot and Hanetz must be equal to the time between Shekiya and Tzeit to ensure that noon stays properly in the middle. Pesachim 93-94 is RT's source and it is clear that the time on either side of sunrise/sunset is the same 4-5 mil.

Comment: To be clear, this assumes, following the website you asked about, that the morning and afternoon hours must be of equal length. Without that assumption, there's no need to conclude that MA follows RT.

Answer (score 3):

According to MA day lasts from Dawn till Tzeis Hakochavim of R.Tam. 
It looks like Sunset on MyZmanim is calculated by other shita than R.Tam (maybe GR"A). That's why it looks like Plag Haminha of MA is 2 minutes before sunset.

[Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/shiur.asp?id=2547) is a source that also states this. In paragraph: השעות הזמניות ודיניהן.

Comment: According to MA, can you daven Mincha any time before Tzeit, as long as you daven Ma'ariv after Tzeit (the way we generally treat sundown)?

Comment: @Isaac everyone (?) holds that Mincha goes to the end of the 12 hours, however you count them