# If צאת is late, then פלג is late. When does one light the מנורה on Friday?

Tags: halacha, zemanim, menora-chanukia, leil-shabbat

One cannot light the *Chanuka* lights before *p'lag hamincha* (*Shulchan Aruch* 672:1), not even on Friday evening (*Mishna B'rura* 679:2). If he did so, his lighting is invalid (*Shaar Hatziyun* 672:4).

*P'lag hamincha* is defined (*MB* 672:3, *Kitzur Shulchan Aruch* 139:10) as a point in time one and one-quarter season-based "hours" before *tzes hakochavim* (when stars come out). That is, divide the length of the day into twelve, choose one of those divisions as an "hour", and subtract one and a quarter such "hours" from *tzes hakochavim*: that's *p'lag hamincha*, the earliest time to light the *Chanuka* lights.

Now, the practice in the United States, at least, is this: No matter how late you consider the day to start and end for other purposes, you consider sunset as the start of *ben hash'mashos* with respect to doing *m'lacha* on *Shabas*. To put it more simply, no one lights a flame after sunset on Friday.

But some hold *tzes hakochavim* is quite late! For example, consider Seattle. During *Chanuka* this year, its day length (sunrise to sunset) is about 8 hours, 25 minutes. Even if we add 72 minutes to the start and end of that for twilight, we have a 10:49-long day; thus, even if we count "hours" including twilight, an "hour" is only 54 minutes and 5 seconds. People who hold of a *tzes hakochavim* that's more than 67.5 minutes after sunset have a *p'lag hamincha* that's after sunset.

When do they light on Friday of *Chanuka*, and on what basis?

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/12282/759

Answer (score 2):

[Mekadesh Yisrael 252](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9663&st=&pgnum=307&hilite=) discusses this and says that even though in such a situation one will light prior to Plag, there is no choice here and that is what must be done.

Comment: He doesn't seem to say whether to say a _b'racha_.

Answer (score 1):

All this applies equally to lighting regular Shabbos candles.

Common practice in America today is to calculate all *z'manim* based on a sunrise-to-sunset day, except for *Sof zman krias sh'ma*, so *P'lag* will always be before sunset. This is true even for those that will e.g. pray *Mincha* until 72 minutes after sunset.

Historically there were places in Europe where they would calculate everything based on a dawn-to-nightfall day, and they would indeed do *Melacha* even after sunset. It was therefore not problematic to have such a late *P'lag*.

Comment: Do you have a source for your second paragraph?

Comment: Equally, except not everyone holds candlelighting for shabbat must be after plag.